# Can't find "Add New" button for themes in a multisite

Tags: multisite, themes

[image: You can see that there is no 'add new' button in this image.]

So, I can't add new themes and I can't find nothing on the wordpress forum too.

Answer (score 4):

This is a multisite. You can add new themes on the network page `/wp-admin/network/themes.php` only. In the **My Sites** menu go to **Network Admin/Themes**. There you will find a list all installed themes and the **Add new** button.

If you cannot access that page, you are not a Super Admin on the network. Super Admins are the only users who can access those sites and install new themes and plugins.