# Themes don't show up in the dashboard -> Appearance -> Themes

Tags: themes, dashboard

On the server in the themes directory, there are these themes: 
[image: themes]

However, in the dashboard there are only these themes shown: 
[image: themes in dashboard]

On my local WP installation they all are shown. How can I solve this?

Comment: Did you set-up the child theme properly by following [these](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) instructions?

Comment: you are on a multisite on the screenshot, read this : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/287622/cant-find-add-new-button-for-themes-in-a-multisite/